# How do I convert MS Smart quotes “ into ascii? using Tool command language (TCL)

Tags: tcl, converters, smart-quotes

I used the following but it does not recognize the smart quotes

```
set EmailSubject [string map -nocase {“ \\u0093  } $EmailSubject]
```

I am using TCL

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues here.

- What is `\u0093` doing there?  That's a control character.
- `\u....` will not be converted when inside braces.
- `-nocase` is not needed, alpha characters are not being converted.
- I recommend using the `\u....` format rather than embedding the `“` characters.

I am also going to make an assumption that by "converting into ascii", you want the ordinary `"` character.  If this is wrong, please update your question.

The characters to convert are \u201C and \u201D, the left and right curly quotation marks.  So the string map command will look like:

```
set EmailSubject [string map [list \u201C \" \u201D \"] $EmailSubject]
```

This converts both \u201C and \u201D into the `"` character.

Comment: `\u0093` is what you'd get if the file was in an encoding like cp1250; Tcl usually handles such things when reading the data so that scripts can internally be working with Unicode.

Comment: used set EmailSubject [string map [list \u201C \" \u201D \"] $EmailSubject] I then use set EmailSubject [string map -nocase {\" \\u0022  } $EmailSubject] because I am going to put this in a JSON payload. ... what are the codes (\\u201C) for the smart single quotes and the smart dash (‘ and’s the dash – )

Comment: I got it ...thank for your help. set EmailSubject [string map [list \u201C \" \u201D \"] $EmailSubject]
  set EmailSubject [string map [list \u2019 ' \u2018 '] $EmailSubject]
  set EmailSubject [string map [list \u2E3A - \u2012 - \u2013 - \u2014 -] $EmailSubject]